# Start redis container with backup dump.rdb

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying do deploy a simple node - redis architecture using docker-compose.

I have a *dump.rdb* with the backup of redis data and I want to launch a container with that data loaded.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
  services:
      redis:
        image: redis:alpine
        container_name: "redis"
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
  server:
    build: ./src
    image: hubName:imageName
    container_name: containerName
    links: 
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - "redis"
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    restart: always
```

Should I include volumes? What if I want persistance of that redis data?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use docker-compose.yml like :

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - /data/redis:/data

  server:
    build: ./src
    image: hubName:imageName
    container_name: containerName
    links: 
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - "redis"
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    restart: always
```

Let's copy your dump.rdb to /data/redis folder on your host machine then start docker-compose.

About redis persistance,you must have docker volume and have two types for redis persinstance: RDB and AOF

- RDB: The RDB persistence performs point-in-time snapshots of your dataset at specified intervals ( example: 60 seconds or if there're at least 10000 keys have been changed)
- AOF: logs every write operation received by the server(eg: SET command) , that will be played again at server startup, reconstructing the original dataset

For more: https://redis.io/topics/persistence

You should decide base on your critical data level. In this case you have rdb dump so you can use RDB, it's default option